# Set datagrid row color based on the value in the datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Datagrid `dgColor` contains two fields:

- `columnA` shows names like a,b,c.
- `columnB`  is a hidden field which contains color code values like `(#ffffff, #ff1211, #1111, #1222)`.

Fill datagrid row color based on the values in `columnB`.

Comment: What have you already tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try but I did not test it with data

```
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" Margin="12,12,0,0">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=colorCol}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: not Working shows error message like "Input string was not in a correct format." . "Red" and  '#ff00ffff' values are used for testing

Comment: At least it is getting a value.  Use a converter to translate the string to a Brush.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already got the color you need for each row you can easily set the colors of each row in the LoadingRow event. I can't test the code where I am now so you probably have to tweak this some, but you can try something like this:

```
private void dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    MyObject myObject = e.Row.Item as MyObject;
    if (myObject != null)
    {
        byte r = byte.Parse(myObject.Color.Substring(1, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        byte g = byte.Parse(myObject.Color.Substring(3, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        byte b = byte.Parse(myObject.Color.Substring(5, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r,g,b));
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
Try the edited code instead. It should do the job.